# How can I response my custom list to the request side?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How can I response my custom list to the request side?

I use `django-rest-framework`:

```
class GetCustomListAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    def get(self, request):

        list = [
            {
                "user": {"name": "David"},
                "passport": 123
            },
            {
                "user": {"name": "Den"},
                "passport": 124
            },
            {
                "user": {"name": "George"},
                "passport": 125
            },

        ]

        return Response() # what should I write in the Response for returning the list back to request side?
```

How can I return the list to the request side?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using the DRF, you can pass to the data param:

```
return Response(data=list, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```